# DB many to many for more than one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I have **posts** table and **content** table and both of them have **tags** and in order to connect them I think I should use many-to-many relational table (that will store each id's).

But I wonder if I need to do it for every new table/content that will associate with the tags table?

So in this case I should have 2 relational tables:

**post_tag**
-> post_id
-> tag_id

**content_tag**
-> content_id
-> tag_id

right?
so if ill have another table, lets say **videos** then I'll have another relational table?
**video_tag**
-> video_id
-> tag_id

And since I work with laravel 4, belongTo and hasMany take care of the queries right?

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to have separate association tables for each usage.  The alternative - to have all the intersections in one table with a flag to distinguish them, will eventually give deeper indexes with more expensive lookups to give but one practical reason.  From a theory point of view you have muddied the primary key with made up values.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into Many to Many Polymorphic Relations (http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations), as a Tag could belong to either a Post, Content or Video model. In fact, the example on the Laravel docs site is very similar to what you propose.